Is it forbidden to name a child after a Rishi?
I have heard that it is considered inappropriate to name a child after a Rishi, such as Vashishta, Parashara, Bhrigu, or Vyasa. Is there any scriptural basis for this belief? Are there specific texts that discourage using Rishi names for naming children?
Additionally, while it is generally acceptable to name children after gods, what if a Rishi's name is also a god's name? Would that make it permissible?

Rishi's names are commonly used as first names (e.g., Vyas) as well as last names (e.g., Bharadwaj, Vashisht) which means this has been prevalent since many centuries. Only those who lack a clear understanding about the Rishis and their actions would make such claims, imo.

Name of Vedas vyasa was Krishna dwaipayan and Lord Krishna was named Krishna
